# SQL check multiple rows with if and get the count

Tags: mysql, sql

Table:

```
id  | name  | country
---------------------
1   | abc   | India
2   | abc   | America
3   | abc   | USA
4   | xyz   | India
5   | xyz   | America
6   | xyz   | USA
```

QUERY tried so far:

```
SELECT `id`,
    if(`country` = 'India',count(id),0) as object1,
    if(`country` = 'America', count(id),0) as object2,
    if(`country` = 'USA',count(id),0) as object3
FROM `table`
```

the above gives me output like this:

```
id  | name  | object1   |   object2 | object3
---------------------------------------------
1   | India | 6         |   0       | 0
```

---

**I want output like :**

```
id  | name      | object1   |   object2 | object3
---------------------------------------------
1   | India     | 1         |   1       | 1     
1   | America   | 1         |   1       | 1
1   | USA       | 1         |   1       | 1
```

Please someone help me out to get this output.

Comment: What are the object counts? There doesn't seem to be any relationship between object1/object2/object3 counts and the total frequency of the different values. What can't you use GROUP BY and name, count(*) ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want conditional aggregation, but it is unclear what the objects are.  Based on the data, I might think:

```
SELECT country as name,
       sum(name = 'abc') as abc,
       sum(name = 'xyz') as xyz
FROM `table`
group by country;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 SELECT `id`,`country`, count(`country`) as 'CountOfCountry'
    FROM `table`
    GROUP by id,Country
```

That will give you a count of each unique country, all grouped.
This is assuming that what you are calling "objects" is really the count per country.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what the third column should be because you don't have the sample data to support it.  But how about the following ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8e6e/2/0)):

```
SELECT country,
  SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'abc' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS object1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'xyz' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS object2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'nunya' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS object3
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY country
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure if you wanted to return the ID with your query as all the IDs in your sample output are 1, and I'm not sure how that would represent the sample data you gave, but assuming that was a typo. This is what I came up with. Here is the sql fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b763d/7

```
select id,country,
(select count(id) from things where country='india') as object1,
(select count(id) from things where country='america') as object2,
(select count(id) from things where country='usa') as object3
from things
```

Now if you dont want the ID and just want things to be grouped by country then do the following.

```
select country,
(select count(id) from things where country='india') as object1,
(select count(id) from things where country='america') as object2,
(select count(id) from things where country='usa') as object3
from things
group by country
```